# how to replace file with an empty file of the same name?

Tags: files

My Set-Up:

When a user uploads a file, it first gets uploaded to a folder on my local server, and then gets moved to an amazon s3 server for storage.  Currently, when the file is moved to s3, the local file gets deleted.

What I would like to do:

Rather than delete the local file, I would like to replace the local file with a 0-byte file.  Reason:  so that if another user uploads a file with the same name, the system will know it needs to rename the second file.

My Question:

How can I replace a file ("myvideo.flv") with an empty file of the same name, so that "myvideo.flv" now contains 0 bytes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To replace a file with a zero byte file use a combination of [`unlink()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) and [`touch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.touch.php):

```
unlink($file_path);
touch($file_path);
```

To move a file to a different folder use Drupal's [`file_move()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_move/7):

```
file_move($src_file_path, $dest_file_path);
```

To rename a file use [`rename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php):

```
rename($file_path);
```

All of the above make the assumption that your webserver user has read access over the source path, and write access to the destination path.

**EDIT**

Your original question asked about moving/renaming files as well, I'll leave the answer to those in just in case you're still wondering.